# If $3a^2+2b^2=3a+2b$ then find the minimum value of $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b(3a+2)}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a(3b+2)}}$

Tags: inequality

> Suppose $a,b$ are positive reals.If $3a^2+2b^2=3a+2b$ then find the minimum value of $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b(3a+2)}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a(3b+2)}}$

I feel this can be done by AM-GM.I failed to use that $3a^2+2b^2=3a+2b$. Some tricky inequalities are needed here.

Comment: One hint is that $f(a,b) := 3a^2 + 2b^2 - 3a - 2b$ is a paraboloid of revolution. So you a trying to maximize the function with the square roots over this paraboloid.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Do anyone have Basic solution without calculus

Answer (score 4):

*Just an ugly exercise for numerical calculation (I gave up with Lagrange multipliers).*

Use the constraint to eliminate $b$ as a function of $a$
$$b_\pm=\frac{1}{2} \left(1\pm\sqrt{-6 a^2+6 a+1}\right)$$ Using $b=b_+$, you are left with
$$f(a)= \sqrt{\frac{2a}{(3 a+2) \left(1+\sqrt{-6 a^2+6
   a+1}\right)}}+\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{-6 a^2+6 a+1}}{7a+3a \sqrt{-6 a^2+6 a+1} }}$$

Computing $f'(a)$ (a small nightmare) and looking for its zero, starting with $a_0=1$, Newton iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & 1.0000000000 \\
 1 & 0.9657338664 \\
 2 & 0.9591954631 \\
 3 & 0.9590355426 \\
 4 & 0.9590354535
    \end{array}
\right)$$
leading to $b= 1.0558144283$ and the minimum value already reported by Michael Rozenberg.

**Cheating**

Assuming that we know that the solution is close to $(1,1)$, let $a=1+\alpha$ and $b=1+\beta$. Expand as Taylor series the constraint to get
 $$3 \alpha +2 \beta=0\implies \beta=-\frac 32 \alpha$$ This makes the function to be
$$g(\alpha)= \sqrt{\frac{2(\alpha +1)}{-9 \alpha ^2-9 \alpha +10}}+\sqrt{\frac{2-3 \alpha
   }{-9 \alpha ^2+\alpha +10}}$$ Using Taylor expansion
$$g(\alpha)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{3 \alpha }{20 \sqrt{5}}+\frac{851 \alpha ^2}{800
   \sqrt{5}}+O\left(\alpha ^3\right)$$
$$g'(\alpha)=\frac{3}{20 \sqrt{5}}+\frac{851 \alpha }{400 \sqrt{5}}+O\left(\alpha ^2\right) \implies \alpha=-\frac{60}{851}\qquad \beta=\frac{90}{851}$$ That is to say $a=\frac{791}{851}\approx 0.929495$ and $b=\frac{941}{851}\approx 1.10576$.

Plugging in $g(\alpha)$ leads to
$$g\left(-\frac{60}{851}\right)=\frac{1}{5} \left(\sqrt{\frac{673141}{153383}}+\sqrt{\frac{800791}{143171}}\right)\approx 0.891982$$

**Update**

Without using the expansion for the constraint, using $b=b_+$ and performing around $a=1$ a Taylor expansion of $f(a)$, we obtain
$$f(a)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{3 (a-1)}{20 \sqrt{5}}+\frac{1751 (a-1)^2}{800
   \sqrt{5}}+\frac{23623 (a-1)^3}{3200 \sqrt{5}}+\frac{9170799 (a-1)^4}{256000
   \sqrt{5}}+O\left((a-1)^5\right)$$ which is minimum for
$$a\approx 0.959646 \implies b\approx 1.05506$$ and a minimum value equal to $0.893133$.

The exact solution is $a\approx 0.959035$, $b\approx 1.05581$ and $f_{min}\approx 0.893132$.

Comment: Can anyone do it WITHOUT using CALCULUS

Comment: @SufaidSaleel. Not me ! Cheers.

Comment: @Sufaid Saleel At least, now do you see that the equality does not occurs for $a= b$? Thank you, Claude! +1